# Facebook Messenger Inbox in a Web Dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot, facebook-chat

I am creating a web dashboard and want to integrate my facebook page messenger inbox on the dashboard, so we do not have to login into facebook or messenger to view and reply to the messages we have received on FB. For example the inboxes that frontapp, smooch provide.

I am not sure if I need to save the messages we get in webhooks and the replies also or we can access it through API.

I am also confused that if I create an app and connect that to the dashboard , that the user can reply from the dashboard and the message will be delivered to the user through the app, is it possible to send the message after the 24 hour window (plus 1 message) fb allows  for apps if they reply from FB app, or it considered as bot as the messages are delivered through app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the page conversations:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/conversations

And then respond to them by conversation ID:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/conversation/messages